# Probability $k$ bins are non-empty.

Tags: pr.probability

The following problem arises in the analysis of [Bloom filters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloom_filter#Probability_of_false_positives).

Consider $m$ bins and $N=nk$ balls placed uniformly at random into the bins.  A query chooses $k$ bins uniformly at random and asks if they are all non-empty.

The main questions asked are "What is the probability that all $k$ bins in the query are non-empty?" and from there "For what $k$ is this probability minimized?".  It is assumed that $k$ should be a function of $m$ and $n$.

The standard version of the analysis taught the world over and reproduced in the wikipedia page linked above contains a "now the magic occurs" step which ignores the non-independence of the bins.

Is there a clean and rigorous way of doing this analysis correctly?

Comment: Just to confirm, the $k$ query bins are not uniformly chosen from the $m \choose k$ subsets, they don't have to be distinct, correct?

Comment: That is correct.

Comment: Just a comment to say the current non-proven answer to the second question is $k \approx \frac{m}{n} \ln{2}$ (from the wiki link).  Given how well used and known Bloom filters are I would guess this is in fact approximately correct.

Comment: It looks like pages 110-111 of http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=0bAYl6d7hvkC&lpg=PA111&ots=onP4AtJavN&dq=bloom%20filters%20independent%20chernoff%20bound%20corollary&pg=PA110#v=onepage&q=bloom%20filters%20independent%20chernoff%20bound%20corollary&f=false has an answer. Unfortunately the relevant results it relies on aren't provided by Google as far as I can see.

Comment: The question was cross-posted to http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/402210/probability-k-bins-are-non-empty .

Answer (score 2):

**UPDATE:**  As Algernon points out, the following analysis is actually wrong, but it's worth trying to spot the error on your own before reading his comment.  :)

Let $B_i$ denote whether the $i$th randomly selected bin is nonempty.  Then the probabilty we seek is
$$
\mathrm{Pr}(B_i=1, \forall i)
=\mathrm{Pr}(B_i=1)^k.
$$
To determine $\mathrm{Pr}(B_i=1)$, it is natural to condition on the random number $X$ of nonempty bins:
$$
\mathrm{Pr}(B_i=1)
=\sum_{x=1}^m\mathrm{Pr}(B_i=1|X=x)\mathrm{Pr}(X=x)
=\sum_{x=1}^m\frac{x}{m}\mathrm{Pr}(X=x)
=\frac{1}{m}\mathbb{E}[X].
$$
Let $X_p$ denote the random number of nonempty bins after $p$ balls.  Then
$$
\mathbb{E}[X_{p+1}|X_p]
=X_p\frac{X_p}{m}+(X_p+1)\frac{m-X_p}{m}
=\Big(1-\frac{1}{m}\Big)X_p+1.
$$
From this, the law of total expectation gives a recursion:
$$
\mathbb{E}[X_{p+1}]
=\mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}[X_{p+1}|X_p]]
=\Big(1-\frac{1}{m}\Big)\mathbb{E}[X_p]+1.
$$
The following formula solves this recursion (you can verify it by induction):
$$
\mathbb{E}[X_p]=m\bigg(1-\Big(1-\frac{1}{m}\Big)^p\bigg).
$$
Considering $X=X_{kn}$, we can put everything together:
$$
\mathrm{Pr}(B_i=1, \forall i)
=\mathrm{Pr}(B_i=1)^k
=\Big(\frac{1}{m}\mathbb{E}[X_{kn}]\Big)^k
=\bigg(1-\Big(1-\frac{1}{m}\Big)^{kn}\bigg)^k.
$$
Surprisingly, this is identical to the answer you get assuming independence.  (!)

Comment: However, the k bins are not distinct, so I think your first inequality does not take that into account.  Gerhard "Ask Me About System Design" Paseman, 2013.05.21

Comment: Excuse, I mean the first equality between probabilities.  Gerhard "Ask Me About System Design" Paseman, 2013.05.21

Comment: @Gerhard: Based on Douglas Zare's clarification, the bins are not selected uniformly from the $\binom{m}{k}$ subsets, so I'm assuming that the bins are drawn independently.  How are you interpreting the problem?

Comment: I think I am interpreting it the same way, but drawing a different (and possibly incorrect) conclusion.  To clarify, one of the possibilities is that bin 1 is chosen 3 times, and bin 2 is chosen (k-3) times.  My (possibly incorrect) conclusion is that the probability for k bins is not the kth power of the probability for 1 bin.  When I have something more substantial I will post it here.  Gerhard "Will Look At It More" Paseman, 2013.05.21 

Comment: I am operating under the assumption that the bins have equal probabilities of being selected.  I think this is a reasonable assumption, considering no distribution on the bins was given.

Comment: I think Dustin is correct: the events $B_i=1$ are independent.  Even conditional on a given distribution of balls they are independent ($i$ is the index of a draw, not the index of a bin). Also, the formula for $E[X_p]$ is elementary and doesn't need a recurrence: $(1-1/m)^p$ is the probability that a particular bin is empty after $p$ balls are thrown in.

Comment: @Brendan:  The linearity of expectation is a tricky thing.  :)

Comment: @Dustin: The variables $B_i$ are not independent: $B_1,B_2,\ldots,B_{i-1}$ contain information about the distribution of the balls, which can be used to predict $B_i$.  Consider, for example, the case $m=2$ and $N$ large.  If we know that $B_1=0$, it means that the balls are all in one bin, increasing the chance of $B_2=0$ from $\sim 0$ to $1/2$.

Comment: @Algemon: You are right, gulp.  $B_1$ and $B_2$ are independent when conditioned on the ball distribution, but not globally.

Comment: Wow, good call!  I'll update my answer accordingly.